# How to resize particles already exist in a particle system of Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2d and game development. I use the particle system in Cocos2d and I want to dynamically resize all the particles that already exist on the screen. I tried to change the startSize, endSize and some other value, but they only influence the particles that will be emitted. So how to achieve the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

everything inherits CCNode which has a scale property. So when you add the particle to the scene you can change the scale then

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *jewelxplodeparticle = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"bam.plist"];
jewelxplodeparticle.position = ccp(100,100);
jewelxplodeparticle.autoRemoveOnFinish = true;
[self addChild:jewelxplodeparticle z:1 tag:1];
jewelxplodeparticle.scale = 3.0f
```

or to get a particle that you have already added do the following.

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *jewelxplodeparticle = (CCParticleSystemQuad*)[self getChildByTag:1];
jewelxplodeparticle.scale = 3.0f
```

Scale works the same as a CCSprite.

Comment: Maybe my question mislead you. But what I want is resize every single particle of one emitter. In other words, I want all the "points" emitted by an emitter bigger or smaller. Your code just scale the whole scen.

Comment: If you want to change all actual look of the particle then you will have to change the particle file in ParticleDesigner. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I want to change it dynamically.

Comment: Ah I see my fault. No idea on how but a quick search brought me to this thread on the cocos2d forums. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5795.  Good luck.